# "bash: ./eclipse: cannot execute binary file" when trying to install Eclipse

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

When I download Eclipse and extract it and write at terminal `./eclipse` I
see this error

```
bash: ./eclipse: cannot execute binary file
```

What can I do?

Comment: [Install The Latest Eclipse Release in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-latest-eclipse-ubuntu-14-04/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem.

I had downloaded the 64-bit version but my system was 32-bit. When I tried the 32-bit version of Eclipse, extracted it and in the eclipse folder wrote in terminal

```
./eclipse
```

it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to implement difficult compilation methods to install eclipse. It is in the Official Ubuntu Repository.

You can install `eclipse` as:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Comment: it is old version 3.6 many plugins are unsupported with that version

Comment: what plugins needed? see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=eclipse&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) and you can install.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps to get the latest Eclipse (4.4) up and running. Mkae sure you've got

### Extract and Install Eclipse 4.4

- Download Eclipse 4.4
- Extract the eclipse folder to your Desktop
- Open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and run the following command: `sudo chown -R root:root ~/Desktop/eclipse && mv ~/Desktop/eclipse /opt/eclipse-luna`.
- `sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse-luna/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse-luna`

You should now be able to launch eclipse from terminal using the command `eclipse-luna`

### Create a launcher for Unity

- `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`
  , and then enter the following:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]  
  Type=Application  
  Name=Eclipse  
  Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment  
  Icon=eclipse  
  Exec=eclipse  
  Terminal=false  
  Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
  ```
- Then exit nano with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. Press <kbd>y</kbd> when prompted to save the file.

You should now have a launcher for eclipse in your launcher.

Comment: I did but then >bash: /usr/local/bin/eclipse-luna: cannot execute binary file

Comment: Make sure your JDK is properly installed.

Comment: i remember i install it but how can i found it work properly?